# Selenium: Extract Images via Index

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I'm aware you can extract images using XPath, CSS or by ID. However, there are images which do not have a unique ID (or any other attribute). The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="altImages" class="a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left" style="width:40px;margin-left:-40px;_margin-left:-20px;float:left;">
  <div id="thumbs-image" class="a-hidden" customfunctionname="(function(id, state, onloadFunction){ P.when('A').execute(function(A){ A.trigger('image-block-twister-swatch-click', id, state, onloadFunction); }); });"/>
  <ul class="a-nostyle a-button-list a-vertical a-spacing-top-micro">
    <li class="a-spacing-small template">
      <span class="a-list-item">
        <span class="a-declarative" data-thumb-action="{}" data-action="thumb-action">
          <span id="a-autoid-10" class="a-button a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle">
            <span class="a-button-inner">
              <input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-10-announce"/>
              <span id="a-autoid-10-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
                <span class="placeHolder"/></span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="a-spacing-small item">
      <span class="a-list-item">
        <span class="a-declarative" data-thumb-action="{"index":"0", "thumbnailIndex":"0", "type": "image", "variant": "MAIN"}" data-action="thumb-action">
          <span id="a-autoid-10" class="a-button a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle">
            <span class="a-button-inner">
              <input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-10-announce"/>
              <span id="a-autoid-10-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
      </li>
      <li class="a-spacing-small item">
        <span class="a-list-item">
          <span class="a-declarative" data-thumb-action="{"index":"1", "thumbnailIndex":"1", "type": "image", "variant": "PT01"}" data-action="thumb-action">
            <span id="a-autoid-10" class="a-button a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle">
              <span class="a-button-inner">
                <input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-10-announce"/>
                <span id="a-autoid-10-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="a-spacing-small item">
          <span class="a-list-item">
            <span class="a-declarative" data-thumb-action="{"index":"2", "thumbnailIndex":"2", "type": "image", "variant": "PT02"}" data-action="thumb-action">
              <span id="a-autoid-10" class="a-button a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle a-button-selected a-button-focus">
              <span class="a-button-inner">
                  <input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-10-announce"/>
                 <span id="a-autoid-10-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 </span>
              </span>
            </span>
        </li>
```

The ID for all elements is `id="a-autoid-10-announce"`. The only difference between the elements is this part: `data-thumb-action="{"index":"0", "thumbnailIndex":"0"`- where the value starts from 0 and moves upward. Is it possible to use this value somehow to uniquely identify each element?

P.S

I'm aware I could use findElements and extract a list and iterate through the list but I was wondering if this would work too. I'm Java and Selenium. The product I am viewing is: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00I8BIBCW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I8BIBCW).

Thanks!

Comment: There is not any image element your code. which element exactly do you want to get? your question is not clear enough

Comment: The locator will be used to identify an image later.. the primary intent of the question is - is there a way to use the values above as a unique identifier..?

Comment: `id="a-autoid-10-announce"` - there are 3 of them on the page..

Comment: I'm not going to help you break Amazon's terms of service. You shouldn't be scraping their site.

Answer (score 0):

You can take all elements having same id in a list and then iterate through list for taking action against individual element. Something like below:

```
List<WebElement> imgList = driver.findElements(By.id("a-autoid-10-announce"));
for(WebElement img : imgList)

  {
     //do something with image.
     System.out.println(img.getText());

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='a-autoid-10-announce'][index_no]"))
```

you can access to each element by changing index_no